# Side limits of ${\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)|}{1 + 2^{1/x}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I need to find the side limits of this function if they exist. I've tried dividing both denominator and numerator with $\frac1x$, but that didn't help either. According to the book, the left-side limit doesn't exist, and the right-side limit is $1$. How could I solve this problem?

$${\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0}\frac{|\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)|}{1 + 2^{1/x}}}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**:

in both cases, set $u=\dfrac1x$.

For the right-hand side, use  that $|\sin u|\le 1$.

For the left-hand side, use that if there were a limit, every subsequence would have the same limit and use that the denominator tends to $1$. Can you prove that $\sin\frac1x$ has no limit at $0$?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
L &=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{|\sin(1/x)|}{1+2^{1/x}}\\
&= \lim _{t\to \infty \:}\frac{\left|\sin \left(t\right)\right|}{1+2^t}\\
& \leq \lim _{t\to \infty \:}\frac{1}{1+2^t}\\
& = 0
\end{align}